# How to escape '[' and ']' in GLOB?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to use GLOB operator to determine if some characters are presented in a string:

```
SELECT *
FROM Test
WHERE num GLOB '*[~!?.;:+=()<>_#%&/\\]*'
```

It works fine with '][' at the beginning of the pattern:

```
WHERE num GLOB '*[][~!?.;:+=()<>_#%&/\\]*'
```

But it returns nothing when placing '[]' anywhere in the pattern:

```
WHERE num GLOB '*[[]~!?.;:+=()<>_#%&/\\]*'
```

What's the reason of such behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `]` character ends a character list. So `[[]` is a character list that contains only `[`.

An empty character list would not make sense, so as an exception, putting the `]` directly behind the opening `[` (`[]...]`) can be used to include the `]` character in the list. But that is the only exception.

(For similar reasons, `-` as a literal character must be the last one in the list.)

Comment: Do you mean exactly '*[]...]'? Is ot possible to use escape symbols?

Comment: GLOB does not have an escape character.

Comment: so, if i want to detect both '[' and ']', i have to type pattern like "*[][...]*"?

Comment: Yes. (The `[` can be anywhere because it is not special inside a list.)